# TypeError: Cannot read property [id] of undefined, react-redux useSelector with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to use react-redux-firebase and fetch document with ID from firebase. But constantly getting this error on the title.

[This is how the react dev tools looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIYtT.png)

The code i am executing is:

```
const id = 'first'
useFirestoreConnect([
    {
        collection: 'nodes', doc:id
    }
])

useSelector(({firestore: {data}) => data.nodes[id])
```

I am pretty new with Firestore and React and chouldn't figure out the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that data is not empty during the initialization of the component ?

It might be that useSelector is called before the data.nodes initialization.